# Distant access to /home directory using bind or symlink

Tags: linux, mount, directory, symlink, home

I have a hard drive Data(**FAT32**) and I want it to contain my `/home/username` directory and its content so that the `/home/username` directory is 'artificial'.

I have attempted to :

- use symlink (`ln -s /mnt/Data/hosted_home /home/username`) after copied the `/username` directory
- use mount bind (`mount --bind /mnt/Data/hosted_home /home/username`) + add to the `fstab`

Both solutions ended up failing log in. I am stuck at the log-in screen after reboot nor the correct password nor the fact that I undo my change from terminal (which consist basically in renaming `/home/username_recovery` as `/home/username`) can help me log in with the user account.

So, if someone can come up with a solution to the problem and optionally explain to me (I am very new to Linux/Unix) why my log in has been corrupted and why undoing things just did not fix the issue, that would be very nice.

Also and maybe that can help solving the problem : when I am copying the files to my Data directory, I have failure for symlinks (e.g `.local/...`) which is normal, but could possibly cause the issue.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/98314/358822 But the more fundamental q is Why are you doing this?

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what I want but I thank you. And the reason is DATA partition, but I am think of just symlink Downloads, Music, etc. I did want to add all the .app directories but for now it is fine.

Comment: But why use fat?

Comment: Using FAT might bring unexpected problems later. For example, `ssh` is picky about the permissions of some of its files. Even if you can login, other things will break, or at least misbehave, depending on your mount flags.

Comment: FAT is the filesystem that both Linux and Mac os can handle ? Am I wrong ? I've seen that HFS+ was bad on some post on ulse, so I am a bit lost. I do agree however that having a FS that can handle symlink would allow me to do precisely what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment

> ...filesystem that both Linux and Mac os can handle...

finally narrows down the **Why?**

## tl;dr

What you want should be doable in parts but not in combination.

## In more detail

#### “Handle...”

Handle has many shades

1. Native: Linux is most happy with ext4 (and reiser and...) These are *native* FSes.
2. Linux (and I guess Mac of which I know almost nothing) can read/write/create FAT. But permissions etc are unsatisfactory for OS use
3. Linux can just about read ntfs but writing has all kinds of gotchas

Also `/home/username` is not really quite “yours” even though it may seem so. In particular the files starting with "." and under `.local` `.config` etc are really v much shared between you and various apps/OS. So having 2 OSes contend there is a bad idea.

## So

1. You can read/write FAT. And mount it wherever you like *under* `/home/username`
2. You can mount a native FS like ext4 *on* `/home` or `/home/username`
3. You can automate/systematize above in `/etc/fstab` (Or if you want to go fancy systemd mount units!)

After that you can clean up/minimize access by symbolic links : eg `$HOME/Pictures` to `$HOME/Data/Pictures`

where Data is your mounted FAT disk

Or make separate Downloads Music Pictures etc FAT partitions on disk and mount them individually under corresponding points under your $HOME.
Note : $HOME itself being ext4 (say) would allow symlinks

Comment: Thanks, I decided to reformat the common partition in HFS+, disabling journaling. The solution with symlinks worked perfectly. However I do not want to share home directories I intended to have distinct directories for  both home and symlinks the common files in a User directory (e.g Documents, Downloads...)